# Intent for being able to be launched after installation

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, intentfilter

which Intent receiver do I need in my manifest so that my app can be launched from the details page on the Market? I have an app released on the market, but when people install it from the market they can only see the "Uninstall" button and there is no "Open". Any ideas? Best, phoku